# How to convert CMSampleBuffer to CMAttachmentBearer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm new of swift, I want to call function `CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments` in `(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection` delegate

Codes of mine:

```
// MARK: Delegates

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    // got an image
    let pixelBuffer : CVPixelBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    let attachments : CFDictionaryRef = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, CMAttachmentMode( kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate)) as CFDictionaryRef!

}
```

This got an error by xcode :`'CMSampleBuffer' is not identical to 'CMAttachmentBearer'`
so how can I use sampleBuffer as target, this code works if written in objective-c

Answer (score 1):

I guess the major problem in your code is that you passe the `CMSampleBuffer` instead of the `CVPixelBufferRef`.

The next problem then is that `CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments` returns an unmanaged instance, which needs to be converted using `takeRetainedValue()`.

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    // got an image
    let pixelBuffer : CVPixelBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    let attachments : [NSObject : AnyObject] = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBuffer, CMAttachmentMode( kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate)).takeRetainedValue()

}
```